How to Add a Trailing Slash to URLs in Nuxt 3
I have a Nuxt 3 project with a directory public/urlName/ containing an index.html file. When the page is accessed without a trailing slash at the end of the URL, the files and styles located in the same directory do not load. However, everything works fine if a trailing slash is added. How can I add a rule to handle this within the public directory?
sitename.com/urlName - not load css
sitename.com/urlName/ - work
i'm trying add .htaccess, but not work

This can be done with the help of rewrite Rule which can be added to .htaccess if you are using Apache server and nginx config file if you using nginx.
